No recycling in tapply - R - WHY?
I wonder what are the exact rules for recycling in R.
Since some functions like cbind recycle, but tapply does not.
I tried:
tapply(bb, aa, mean)
#> Error in tapply(bb, aa, mean) : arguments must have same length

I like the orthogonality of the language, but in this case I can´t find an explanation.
I expected R to recycle the shortest vector.

There are no 'exact rules' about recycling, there are just functions that were written so as to do it, and functions that were not written to support it. It is a matter of authorship.

It’s documented that they need to be the same length.

If you look at the code of tapply, it includes a line which specifically throws an error if the first two arguments are of different length. The whole idea of tapply is to take a vector, split it into groups according to labels in the second vector, then apply a function to each of those groups. The second vector therefore has to be the same length as the first. Recycling either vector to match lengths seems like a recipe for ambiguities and silent bugs. If I had written tapply I think I would also have insisted that the two input vectors were the same length. Why would it be useful?

Here is a workaround: with(data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 1:2), tapply(a, b, mean))

And another: sapply(split(1:4, 1:2), mean)

I just needed orthogonality of the language to remain perfect, as it generally is :D

Here is an example of how the rep function can be used to do your own recycling.
tapply (1:10,c(1:5,1:5),sum) 
# 1  2  3  4  5 
# 7  9 11 13 15 
tapply (1:10,c(1:5),sum)
# Error in tapply(1:10, c(1:5), sum) : arguments must have same length]

recyle_x_by_y <- \(x,y)rep(x,length.out=length(y))

tapply (1:10,recyle_x_by_y(1:5,1:10),sum)
# 1  2  3  4  5 
# 7  9 11 13 15 

Use at your own risk, I'd imagine its easy to make an improper use of recycling here if used without care, I would guess thats why efforts werent made to directly support it in tapply. 


THANKS! But I don't need to do "manual" recycling.. I was just trying to understand why in that case R designers decided not to recycle.
